# How to check text input changes for certain words?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a web page on which I have added a text field. I have set an ID to the text field (say, 'custom'). Now, I want to modify the webpage if the text field contains certain words.

For example, if the text field contains a word, say apple, I want to do something.

If the text field contains ball, I want to do something else.

And so on.

I had found this:

```
<script>
var check=document.getElementById("custom").value == "text_value";
//check will be true or false
if (check){ //do something if true}
if(!check){//do something if false}
</script>
```

I don't even know if it's correct or not, but, I realised, it won't be able to manage multiple conditions. Because, if the text contains apple, it won't contain ball, it will create wierd behaviour.

So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried ? Your code snippet makes no sense.

Comment: `document.getElementById("custom").value.includes("text_value")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please run the code snippet below.

The trigger is `onkeyup` and was selected for demonstration purposes. You can change it as per your requirement, for example, run the javascript function `watchWords` upon pressing a button.

```js
function watchWords()
{
  var watch_words = ['apple', 'lemon', 'watermelon'];
  var textvalue = document.getElementById('name').value;
  for(var i=0; i<watch_words.length; i++) {
    if (~textvalue.indexOf(watch_words[i])){

      if(watch_words[i] == 'apple'){
        console.log('Apple was found');
      }
      
      if(watch_words[i] == 'lemon'){
        console.log('Lemon was found');
      }
      
      if(watch_words[i] == 'watermelon'){
        console.log('Watermelon was found');
      }
      
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" onkeyup="watchWords()" />
```

Comment: @HrishikeshKokate - you can accept this as an answer if you want for others future reference, thank you.

Comment: Actually, almost all the answers are correct. So, I don't know which one to mark as correct.

Comment: accept the first answer who made it work the first time i guess?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the following **Vanilla JavaScript** (plain JavaScript) example.

I.e. enter `bla bla apple` and you will get the expected result.

```js
function doSomething() {
  var text = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

  if (text.includes("apple")) {
    console.log("do something special because text contains apple");
  }
  else if (text.includes("ball")) {
    console.log("do something special because text contains ball");
  }
  else {
    console.log("text contains no special word");
  }
}
```

```html
Enter text: <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="doSomething()">
```

Comment: This one works, but, only if the text is only the word apple. I mean, if the word apple is in a sentence, like, 'I have an apple', this doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @HrishikeshKokate. I updated my answer. Your example `I have an apple` should work.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an object indexed by the `.value`s you want to identify, whose property values are the functions you you want to run for each, eg:

```
const objOfFns = {
  apple() {
    console.log('Apple!');
  },
  ball() {
    console.log('Ball!');
    bounceBall();
  }
};

const { value } = document.getElementByid('custom');
const possibleFn = objOfFns[value];
// check hasOwnProperty to avoid accidentally referencing Object.prototype methods
if (possibleFn && objOfFns.hasOwnProperty(value) {
  possibleFn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery `on keyup` event listener and `includes` function:

```
$("#custom").on("keyup", function() {
  if (this.value.includes("apple")) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

The code above will check the `custom` input each time the user presses a key and execute the `if` block if the input string contains the word `apple`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function common(arr1, arr2) {
    var newArr = [];
    newArr = arr1.filter(function(v){ return arr2.indexOf(v) >= 0;})
    newArr.concat(arr2.filter(function(v){ return newArr.indexOf(v) >= 0;}));

    return newArr;
}

var string = document.getElementById("custom").value;
var items = string.split(" ");

var yourlist = ["apple", "banana", "tomato"];

var intersection = common(yourlist, items);

for(i=0; i<intersection.length; i++){
    console.log(intersection[i]);
    var z = yourlist.indexOf(intersection[i]);
    /* Your Logic Goes Here.. */
    if(z == 0){
        /* do something */
    }else{
        /* do something else */
    }
}
</script>
```

Function Credits - https://gist.github.com/IAmAnubhavSaini